# Enabling CORS on Firebase Storage for localhost tests

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

My web app will run on Firebase Hosting, but I need to test it locally through `firebase serve` on `localhost:5000`
I am incurring in a CORS error while trying to read a file on Firebase Storage.

I have followed [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers), and added the relative heading section to firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
  "headers": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [ {
        "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
        "value": "*"
      } ]
    }]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}
```

But this didn't fix. I am still blocked on CORS error.

**EDIT with solution**

I have fixed this by using the python library and a short script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import storage


CREDFILE = home + 'credentials.json'
cred = credentials.Certificate(CREDFILE)
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'storageBucket': '<myapp>.appspot.com'
})
bucket = storage.bucket()

bucket.cors = [{
  'origin': ['*'],
  'method': ['GET'],
  'maxAgeSeconds': 86400
}]

bucket.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to set up storage cors using `gsutil`:

1. Install gsutil from [cloud.google.com](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install), connect your google account

2. Backup current setup with `gsutil cors get <MY_FIRESTORE_BUCKET>`, where `<MY_FIRESTORE_BUCKET>` is the address of your firestore bucket in following format: `gs://example.appspot.com`
3. Create `json` file with cors setup, eg `my-cors.json`:

```
[
 {
 "origin": ["*"],
 "method": ["GET"],
 "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
]
```

4. Navigate in command prompt to `my-cors.json` file, and set that file as a new cors config for your bucket with this  command:
   `gsutil cors set my-cors.json <MY_FIRESTORE_BUCKET>`